# Extending Material UI theme via Module Augmentation not working correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to extend `Theme` with Material UI, but it's throwing an error, saying that I'm not extending it correctly, saying,

```
Property 'layout' is missing in type 'Palette' but required in type 'IPaletteOptions'.
```

Here is what I have:

```
// src/theme/theme.d.ts
import { Theme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import {
  IPaletteOptions,
  PaletteOptions
} from "@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette";

type TLayout = {
  primary: string;
  secondary: string;
};

declare module "@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette" {
  export interface IPaletteOptions extends PaletteOptions {
    layout: TLayout;
  }
}

declare module "@material-ui/core/styles" {
  export interface ITheme extends Theme {
    palette: IPaletteOptions;
  }
}
```

```
// src/theme/index.ts
import { createMuiTheme, ITheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { IPaletteOptions } from "@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette";

export const palette = {
  layout: {
    primary: "#ffffff",
    secondary: "#e4e4e4"
  }
} as IPaletteOptions;

export default createMuiTheme({ palette }) as ITheme;
```

```
// src/App.tsx
import React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider, ITheme } from "@material-ui/core";
import theme from "./theme";

import Component from "./Component";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider<ITheme> theme={theme}>
      <Component />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

```
import { useTheme } from "@material-ui/core";
import React from "react";

export default React.memo(() => {
  const theme = useTheme(); // <-- this should be of type `ITheme` automatically
                            // If I do useTheme<ITheme>(), it shows property 'layout', but
                            // I shouldn't have to do that, because of the type casting that
                            // I do in App.tsx, where I import and use 'theme' from src/theme/index.ts

  return <div>the layout primary color is {theme.palette.layout.primary}</div>;
});
```

What am I doing wrong here? I would like to use `ITheme` throughout my app, which would extend the basic `Theme` in addition to what I add.

[image: cool-matsumoto-4621h]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm thinking of it would be even handy to override things which uses your `ITheme` like as following:

`theme.d.ts`

```js
declare module "@material-ui/core/styles" {
  export interface ITheme extends Theme {
    palette: IPaletteOptions;
  }
  
  // Keep overriding these things in your app
  // In this case returns `ITheme`
  export function createMuiTheme(options?: ThemeOptions, ...args: object[]): ITheme;
  
  // returns `ITheme`
  export function useTheme<T = ITheme>(): T;
}
```

Then you no longer need to cast returned type anymore in your `theme/index.ts`:

```js
export default createMuiTheme({ palette });
```

In case of using `useTheme`, it's supposed to return `ITheme` as expected.

NOTE: I've also updated the codesandbox as well: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-pasteur-s6h8v?file=/src/Component.tsx

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Also, please note that TS is still complaining in your Sandbox (`Interface 'ITheme' incorrectly extends interface 'Theme'. Types of property 'palette' are incompatible. `)

Comment: This was your setup before. It looks like the new type of  `palette` `IPaletteOptions` is not 100% compatible with current one `Theme["palette"]`. But we could fix by setting like this `export type ITheme = Theme & { palette: IPaletteOptions }`. Check the new change here: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-pasteur-s6h8v?file=/typings/theme.d.ts

Answer (score 8):

In Material v5 you can extend `CommonColors`

```
declare module "@mui/material/styles/createPalette" {
  interface CommonColors {
    layout: {
      offBlack: string;
      offWhite: string;
    }
  }
}

const colors = createTheme({
  palette: {
    common: {
      layout: {
        offBlack: "#14142B",
        offWhite: "#FCFCFC",
      },
    },
  },
});

// In a component
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  target: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.layout.offBlack
  }
}));
```

Comment: Do you have a link to your project ?

Comment: Thanks for this, it's extremely helpful to see that you have the special path in `declare module "@mui/material/styles/createPalette"` to override this

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by using this:

```
declare module '@material-ui/styles' {
  export interface DefaultTheme extends CustomTheme {}
}
```

Notice 'core' is not included in the module.

My full code:

```
import theme from './theme';

type CustomTheme = {
  palette: typeof theme;
};

declare module '@material-ui/styles' {
  export interface DefaultTheme extends CustomTheme {}
}
```

Comment: do you have a link to your project ? I would like to know how your different files are organized and called